Copying and pasting text in the new editor, without clipboard events enabled, truncates the rest of the text
Steps to reproduce:

Disable clipboard events in browser settings (for Firefox, this is dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled in about:config).

Edit a question with the new editor - for example by editing any Staging Ground question.

Select some text from the middle of the post, and cut it with Ctrl-X.

Immediately press Ctrl-V to paste the text.


Expected result: the cut text is restored.
Actual result: everything past the insertion point is truncated.

The problem still occurs if the insertion point is relocated before pasting.
I can reliably reproduce this with any part of the text, whether it's multiple lines, a single line or part of a line.
The problem does not occur in the traditional editor, only the one used by the Staging Ground and the Ask Wizard.
Pressing Ctrl-V a second time reliably pastes the text, but doesn't restore anything that was truncated.
Repeatedly pressing Ctrl-Z to undo reliably restores the post to how it was before, as expected.
Using right-click->paste in the browser does not affect the result, so this is not a key-binding issue but something to do with how pasted text is handled.
Using right-click->paste without formatting in the browser does make it work properly. This is especially strange because, as far as I can tell, the copied text doesn't actually have any formatting.
The truncation behaviour is really bizarre. I could understand if pasting simply didn't work under these conditions (lots of other sites seem to have that problem) but it seems like you'd have to go out of your way to create this result.
